Counting degree-$14$ polynomials $p(x)$ whose coefficients are $0$ or $1$ such that the coefficients of $p(x)(x^3+x+1)$ are also $0$ or $1$
The problem is from the IOQM-2024 contest.

Consider the set $F$ of all polynomials whose coefficients are $0$ or $1$. Let $q(x)= x^3 + x + 1 $
Find the number of polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $14$ in $F$ such that the product $p(x)q(x)$ is also in $F$.

My attempt:
Of the terms in $p(x)$, no two terms should have a power differing by 3 or 2 or 1, otherwise we would have two like terms, which would add up, raising the co-efficient from one. So the possible terms in $p(x)$ which may be paired with $x^{14}$ are:
$$ x^{10},x^9,x^8,x^7,x^6,x^5,x^4,x^3,x^2,x,1 $$
But, these terms don't go with every other term, and I was not able to finish the counting. How is the counting finished, and is there another method?
Thanks

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!

Hint: If $p(x) = \sum x^ {a_i}$ in increasing order, what can we say about the sequence $a_i - 3i$?

@Will.Octagon.Gibson yes, that is obvious. I meant the terms which can be paired with $x^14$

Hint : work on $4 \times 10$ arrays $A$ with entries 0 and 1, (and $A_{1,1}=1$) and keep those who have all their sums along ascending diagonals equal to $0$ or $1$.

You could create a simple recurrence based on your " no two terms should have a power differing by 3 or 2 or 1" which can then be used to find the $14th$ term.

Using the same idea as Henry: one can define $T_n$ to be the number of $p(x) \in F$ of degree $n$ s.t. $q(x)p(x) \in F$. We define $T_0 = 2$, $T_1 = T_2 = T_3 = 1$ and $T_4 = 2$. Then $T_n = \sum_{r=0}^{n-4} T_{r}$. Thus $T_{14} = \boxed{50}$. I can upload my work later.

First, a delve straight to the answer as indicated in my comment using the same idea mentioned by Henry. Let's define $T_n$ to be the number of possible $p(x) \in F$ s.t. $p(x)q(x) \in F$ where $q(x) = x^3 + x + 1$.

Claim: $T_0 = 2$ and $T_1 = T_2 = T_3 = 1$.


Claim: $T_n = \sum_{r=0}^{n-4} T_r$ for $n\geq 4$.

I shall prove these  later. One can then manually calculate that $\boxed{T_{14} = 50}$, the answer to the exercise.

Consider an $n$-th degree polynomial, $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i \in F$. Since $a_n \neq 0$ we have $a_n=1$. We have $$f(x) = p(x)q(x) = a_nx^{n+3} + a_{n-1}x^{n+2} + (a_{n} + a_{n-2})x^{n+1} + \sum_{r=3}^{n} \left(a_r + a_{r-1} + a_{r-3}\right) x^r +  (a_2 + a_1)x^2 +(a_1 + a_0)x + a_0$$

Fact $1$: $a_n=1\implies a_{n-3} = a_{n-2} = a_{n-1} = 0$ for $n\geq 3$.

Proof: $a_n$ occurs in exactly $3$ terms in $f(x)$, viz. $x^{n+3}$, $x^{n+1}$ and $x^n$. Since their coefficients $\geq 1$ but also $\in \{0,1\}$ it follows $[x^{n+1}]f(x) = [x^n]f(x) =1$. It follows that $a_{n-3} = a_{n-2} = a_{n-1} = 0$.
Using this claim it follows $T_3 = 1$. Using similar reasoning $T_2 = T_1 = 1$. For $T_0$ both $p(x) = 0$ and $p(x) = 1$ work so $T_0=2$.
To build the recurrence: All of the coefficients $\{a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{n-4}\}$ can be either $0$ or $1$. Consider some $a_r$. If it is $1$ then it suffices to find $T_{r}$; if it is $0$ then we can move to $a_{r-1}$ and repeat until $a_0$. This process starts from $r=n-4$. Thus $T_n = T_{n-4} + T_{n-5} + T_{n-6} + \dots + T_0 = \sum_{r=0}^{n-4} T_{r}$.
Note that for the sake of simplification I consider the zero polynomial to be constant. Without this convention one can take $T_0=1$ but to compensate the zero polynomial in the count of $T_n$ one must rewrite $T_{n} = 1 + \sum \dots$

As an aside, you have the recurrence relation $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-4}$, though the roots of the characteristic polynomial don't seem to be that nice, so the closed form eludes us.$\quad$ Apart from taking the difference of your equation, we could show this directly by conditioning on whether $p(x)$ has a constant term ($T_{n-4}$ ways) or not ($T_{n-1}$ ways).

That's a nice recurrence for $T_n$. It's also easier for manual computation for $T_{14}$.

Thanks, though I think your proof is a bit wordsome , I think its easier to build up the recurrence than to start with the recurrence and then prove it. Btw, a thing I think should be mentioned is, the recurrence is actually $T_n= \sum^{n-4}_{r=0} +1 - 1$ What the recurrence is counting is the number of ways terms can be added to $x^{14}$, but we dont have to add anything, we can just keep $x^{14}$ alone, and -1 because we have already counted that as $x^{14} + 0$. Of course it doesn't matter, but +0 is not really a term and most people don't think of 0 when thinking of terms.

@AravPatnaik I don't think I understand your comment. What do you mean by $T_n = \sum_{r=0}^{n-4} +1 - 1$? Also this recurrence is built on whether some term $x^r$ would appear in $p(x)$ or not . Further, presenting the recurrence before how I built it was a matter of presentation.

+1 - 1 cancel out, getting 0, getting to your recurrence relation.

"Also this recurrence is built on whether some term $x^r$ would appear in $p(x)$ or not" is what I meant by saying "what the recurrence is counting is the number of ways terms can be added to $x^{14}$". I was stating that, how 0 being taken as a constant simplifies the recurrence relation, should have been mentioned in your answer (which I explained in my comment).

I understand your comments now. You're right, but once you play around with how to build the recurrence the reasoning you mention is clear -- the "constant" term can be chosen in two ways, either $0$ or $1$ and the both of them work, thus $T_0 = 2$ simplifes the calculation.

Elaborating upon my hint, suppose that $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k x^{a_i}$ satisfies the conditions, where $a_i$ is in increasing order, then OP+Will states that $ a_i - a_{i-1} > 3, a_k = 14 $ is a necessary and sufficient condition, so let's count the number of such sequences by creating a bijection.
Define $b_i = a_i - 3(i-1)$.
Observe that

$a_i - 3(i-1)  > a_{i-1} - 3(i-2)$, so $b_i$ is a sequence of increasing integers.
$a_k = 14$, so $b_k = 17 - 3k$ is a fixed value.
$b_{k-1} \leq 16 - 3k$
$b_1 = a_1 - 3\times (1-0) = a_0 \geq 0$.

Conversely, given any $k-1 \geq 0$ distinct non-negative integers $\{b_i\}_{i=0}^{k-1}$ from $0$ to $16-3k$ arranged in increasing order, alongside $b_k = 17-3k$ we can define $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k x^{b_i + 3i}$ that fulfills the conditions. This establishes the bijection.
For a given $k$, there are ${ 17 - 3k \choose k -1 }$ such integers. Thus, the number of solutions is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty { 17-3k \choose k -1 } = { 14 \choose 0 } + {11 \choose 1 } + {8 \choose 2 } +  {5 \choose 2 }  = 50. $$
More generally, there are $\sum_{k\geq 0 } { n - 3k \choose k } $ polynomials of degree $n$ that satisfy the condition.
